# Как написать аппликацию похожую на DevicePairingWizard.exe чтобы спаривать Bluetooth до логин Windows 10?

Tags: bluetooth

Привет.
Как написать аппликацию похожую на "DevicePairingWizard.exe" чтобы спаривать Bluetooth до логин Windows 10 ?
Как это сделать после - я знаю.
Но до логина я получаю "Access Denied".
"DevicePairingWizard.exe" может это сделать до.
Какой API (c,c++ ,c# - не важно) он использует? Допустим MAC адрес известен.
Спасибо.

Comment: А из-под какого пользователя вы запускаете приложение? Может, проблема в этом?

Comment: В том-то и проблема , что user ещё нет

Comment: Ну, вы ж можете запустить приложение из-под любой учётки даже если юзер не залогинился

Comment: System или admin (runas) - не помогает. "DevicePairingWizard.exe" - работает. Может знаете , как реализован ?   Для  любой учётки - нужно спрашивать - user name & password, а это не красиво

Comment: Окей, а _как именно_ вы запускаете приложение?

Comment: ShellExecuteEx + runas

Comment: Подождите, а как получает управление ваш код с ShellExecuteEx?

Comment: я запускаю  command line application и передаю параметры

Comment: Хм, а как вы её запускаете до логина?